# Qt how to connect a signal to a slot with the highest priority (even if other slots are connected in advance)

Tags: c++, qt

For some reason, I need a later connected slot to be called first in Qt.

```cpp
connect(action, &QAction::triggered, obj1, &MyObject::slot1);
connect(action, &QAction::triggered, obj2, &MyObject::slot2);
```

What need I do to make the `slot1` to be firstly called?

Comment: (_For some reason_) that reason is important for context, could you tell us about it? What are these actions and what triggers them? And the order of connecting slots to signals does not matter when calling them.

Comment: The action is created by a plugin, and it will be registered to application. The application need to do something before a plugin slot of its action is called. The problem is, the plugin may connect the action to its slot before registering it.

Comment: signals/slots have no idea of `priority` so no - it's not possible,

Answer (score 1):

You need an intermediate QObject (your own subclass). It has one incoming slot, and two (or more) outgoing signals, one signal for each priority you need. These need to have parameters matching the original signal.

Connect the original signal to this intermediate slot of an instance you create for the puroose. That slot will then emit the intermediate signals in priority order. You connect your original receiving slots to these intermediate signals of the same intermediate object.

---

But if you have a possibility to chance the API of the original class, you could add the higher priority signal (emitted first) directly to it. Much simpler.